# Tracking only the page, not the querystring

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, privacy

I'm looking to track only the page the user visits, not the querystring (for privacy reasons).

Is this valid?

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', document.location.pathname]);
```

So a page that's:

x.com/section/page/?test=123

will be logged as

/section/page

Cheers

Comment: I have to wonder what is being passed in the URL that you are concerned about privacy issues...you should NEVER pass private information in the URL, regardless of whether or not GA is being used. You do know that your URL and query string can be seen by pretty much everyone and everything, right? Even if you remove it from your own tracking implementation, it's still going to be tracked or seen by untold amounts of other things, from people scanning network traffic, to browser addons doing their own tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that will work perfectly fine. Passing that second argument will log a pageview using that value rather than the default value Google Analytics would be passing (`location.pathname+location.search`), and the pageviews will appear without the query string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way and NEVER pass the value to Google Analytics, or you can apply a filter in GA to exclude the part after the query string with a regular expression (I believe you even have the option in your Profile configuration now).

This might be more useful if you plan on using some query string parameters for other purposes - internal searches, user language, etc.